# Como guardo un valor Hexadecimal en BBDD?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Bueno mi consulta es esa... ¿Como se guarda un valor hexadecimal en MySQL?

estoy recibiendo el valor por un form method POST como a continuación.

```html
    <form action="guardarendb.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="nombre" value="">
      <input type="color" name="favcolor" value="#fff">
      <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

y lo recibo de la siguiente manera...

```html
<?php
$varcolor = isset($_POST['favcolor']) ? $_POST['favcolor'] : '';
$varnombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : '';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (nombre, color_titulo) VALUES ('$varnombre','$varcolor')"; 

    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); 
    if (!$result){ 
        echo "ERROR: No se pudo guardar la informacion, contacte al administrador."; 
    }else{ 
        echo "<b>Información guardada correctamente.</b>";
        header('Location: index.php'); 
    } 
    ?>
```

Y esa columna en la tabla la cree de la siguiente manera

```
ALTER TABLE tabla ADD color_titulo VARCHAR(10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes escapar los caracteres especiales:
**Cambia:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (nombre, color_titulo) VALUES ('$varnombre','$varcolor')"; 
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

**Por esto:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (nombre,color_titulo) VALUES (?,?)"; 
$query =mysqli_prepare($mysqli,$sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "ss", $varnombre,$varcolor);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
```

Referencia:
[Mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Me sirvió muchas gracias